# Converting hours (time span) into days, weeks, months

Tags: excel

I get the result of `186:12:00` hours:minutes:seconds when I calculate the difference of 2 dates.

How can I convert this to the # of days? or weeks? or months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For days change the format to Number, for weeks, divide that by `7`, for months decide how many days there are in your `month` and divide by that instead of `7`.

Comment: thanks, that was confusing me.. I was thinking it was stored in hours, but really it is represented as hours but stored as day.. I couldn't for the life of me figure out why dividing totals hours by 24 gave me a small fraction.. now I know why - I was dividing days.